# Ошибка «application failed to start because it could not find or load Qt platform plugin 'windows' in ""»

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

Установил Anaconda для работы с matplotlib

При попытке запустить простейший график в  IDLE в интерактивном режиме получаю такое сообщение:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load Qt platform plugin 'windows' in "".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this ploblem.

Пытался переустановить анаконду, но не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

[Документация matplotlib говорит что IDLE не поддерживается](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html).

В качестве альтернативы, попробуйте ipython notebook, для интерактивных matplotlib графиков https://jupyter.org

Answer (score 0):

В Anaconda же уже включена среда Spyder, в которой эта библиотека нормально работает. Используйте её, мне она кажется весьма удобной. Там, к примеру, есть проверка синтаксиса и на соответствие стандарту PEP8.